# compile find a bad version of gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I use spring boot 2. In a multi java project.

I try to build my main library (no yet java file)

```
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.M7'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.0.M7'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
        testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.0.M7'
}

distributions {
    main{
        baseName = 'common-model'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-parameters"]
}
```

In my gradle/wrapper, i have

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2-bin.zip
```

error i get

> caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException:
>   Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Spring Boot plugin requires
>   Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.13

i don't find any 2.13 version

In my main project i have

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

mainClassName = 'com.zirgon.EmailApplication'

group = 'com.zirgon'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-parameters"]
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    compile project(':common-model')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')

    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: You can add `println "Gradle version: "+GradleVersion.current().getVersion()` to the build file to confirm the version

Comment: 2.13...  strange i delete 2.13 in my .gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-bin/ ... when i reload proejct... i seem to download again 2.13

Comment: It is hard to say without access to the system, but a couple of ideas.  Do you have an old 2.13 version in the zipStorePath? Can you add a wrapper task to the gradle file?

`task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.2'
}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible you might be building the project with gradle installed locally instead of using the wrapper i.e. using `gradle build` instead of `./gradlew build`.

Comment: you saved me! thanks a lot. It solved my issue, I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps I took to fix the same problem.

1. I had a new project with a build.gradle file, but did not have a copy of gradle wrapper in my project directory. I think this caused the default gradle version for my IDE to be used (IntelliJ) and this is an older version.
2. Gradle was already installed on my system.
3. Ran "gradle wrapper" in my project directory.
4. Edited ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and made sure "distributionUrl" was pointed at the gradle version I wanted (4.6 in my case).
5. Reran my build and the correct version was then downloaded and installed. Problem fixed.

I hope this helps someone!

I copied my gradle wrapper folder over from another project, and edited ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Eclipse 2018-2019/STS 4.0/Buildship Gradle 3.0.  I solved the problem by configuring *Eclipse > Gradle > Properties*.

Specifically:

1. *Eclipse > Gradle > Update Gradle Project >*

   ```
   Error: Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 3.4.1
   ```
2. Everything *looked* OK in *Eclipse > Window > Installed Software*  So I checked my Windows user profile directory:

   ```
   Directory of C:\Users\paulsm\.gradle\wrapper\dists
     06/11/2017  09:14 AM    <DIR>          gradle-3.3-all
     12/07/2018  06:23 PM    <DIR>          gradle-3.4.1-bin <-- Eclipse using this version
     11/01/2018  02:38 PM    <DIR>          gradle-4.1-all
     11/01/2018  02:50 PM    <DIR>          gradle-4.4-all
     12/07/2018  03:02 PM    <DIR>          gradle-4.8.1-bin
   ```
3. *Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Gradle > Gradle distribution >* Changed from "Gradle wrapper" => "Specific version: 4.8.1"

[image]

4. Re-ran *Eclipse > Gradle > Update Gradle Project* => SUCCESSFUL
5. This effectively ignores the project's local gradle wrapper settings, and ensures that I'll have the "correct* settings for *ALL* my Eclipse projects going forward.

   I can always re-configure Gradle on a per-project basis (reverting back to 3.4.1 or older) if I ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the Gradle wrapper properties.

Error message:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.4 or later. The current version is Gradle 4.0
```

Change the distributionUrl value in gradle-wrapper.properties (located in /gradle/wrapper/) from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Open gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl property to 4.6 version or newer one.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
```